# Problems w/ Structures 'C'

Tags: c

I need to write a program for the following..i have tried but i do not know where i am going wrong..

Define the structure dollarsQuartersDimes with three simple variables int dollars, int quarters and int dimes to declare monies in dollars, quarters and dimes.

Add two dollarsQuartersDimes monies and store the result in the third dollarsQuartersDimes monies.

Remember to make necessary conversions from dimes and quarters to dollar. 
Note: 10 dimes = 1 dollar and 4 quarters = 1 dollar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int dollars;
    int quarters;
    int dimes;   
    }dollarsQuartersDimes;

void main(){

 dollarsQuartersDimes input1 , input2 , total;

 printf ("Please enter the money in order dollars : quarters : dimes ! ");
 scanf ("%d%d%d" , &input1.dollars, &input1.quarters, &input1.dimes);

 printf ("Please enter again the money in order dollars : quarters : dimes ! ");
 scanf ("%d%d%d" , &input2.dollars, &input2.quarters, &input2.dimes);

 input1.dollars = input1.dollars + (input1.quarters/25) + (input1.dimes/10);
 input2.dollars = input2.dollars + (input2.quarters/25) + (input2.dimes/10);

 total.dollars = input1.dollars + input2.dollars;

 printf ("The total value in dollars is : %d" , total.dollars);
}


}
```

**ERROR : I am getting the error that the return type of error is not int. PLEASE HELP !**

Comment: I can't see a `retrun` statement in your code, and it seems you have an extra `}` at the end

Comment: Start with a working "hello, world" program, and add to it little by little until you get an error.

Comment: FWIW, `inputx.quarters / 25` looks wrong. I guess it should be `inputx.quarters / 4`, since four quarters are a dollar.

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare `main` as `int main`:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is exactly what his problem is.

Comment: Yeah, strange. +1 from me.

Comment: Precision: implicitly there is a `return` at the end, which type is `void` while we expect by default an `int` for `main`

Comment: we're presuming that when he wrote "the return type of error is not int" the actual message was "the return type of main is not int"

Answer (score 3):

After you've fixed the indentation and the glaring imbalance of braces, you'll get to the heart of the matter. Statements like

`input1.dollars = input1.dollars + (input1.quarters/25) + (input1.dimes/10);`

will be performed in *integer arithmetic* as the operands are all integral types. You'll get a lot of truncation of data. (24 quarters will evaluate to zero dollars the way you've written it).

To remedy, replace 25 with 25.0. etc. That forces the division to be carried out in floating point.

And fix your prototype for `main`: should be `int main()`. Formally the program behaviour is *undefined* if you use `void main()`.

Comment: It's implementation-defined whether `void main()` is acceptable; and if not, the program is *ill-formed*. If the implementation defines `void main()` as an alternative signature for main then the program does not have UB. If it does not, then a diagnostic must be issued.

Comment: But some compilers will reserve the right to eat your cat. Much better to obey the standard.

Comment: Oh , for sure. My point was that the compiler can't eat your cat without warning you first :)

Comment: Note: `replace 25 with 25.0` may lead OP to use `input1.dollars = input1.dollars + (input1.quarters/25.0) + (input1.dimes/10.0);` and create another post when `input1.dollars` is not as expected.  Suggest expanding the FP issue.  (P.S. no longer have a cat - so no compiler worries there.)

Comment: That opens a can of worms as the OP may need to use a currency type. I hope that your no longer having a cat was not caused by compiling `void main()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should do your addition first:

```
total.dimes = input1.dimes + input2.dimes;
total.quarters = input1.quarters + input2.quarters;
total.dollars = input1.dollars + input2.dollars;
```

Then the propagate the summing up:

```
// NOTE: Assumes the user enter the number of quarters, not the value in quarters!
total.dollars += total.quarters / 4;
// NOTE: Assumes the user enter the number of dimes, not the value in dimes!
total.dollars += total.dimes / 10;
```

Finish by adjusting the remainders:

```
// NOTE: Assumes the user enter the number of quarters, not the value in quarters!
total.quarters = total.quarters % 4;
// NOTE: Assumes the user enter the number of dimes, not the value in dimes!
total.dimes = total.dimes % 10;
```

The % operator gives the remainder of the division.